# Need help to restore menu/submenu glyphs?

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-10

Hi can anyone tell me how to go about restoring the glyphs in windows 10 menus and submenus?? I was messing about with fonts and seems I did something that nobbled that font.. ?? I have little rectangles where the checks and triangles should be...

Many thanks and kind regards
Piers

Comment: I think people need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: Would you be able to add a screenshot ? It might help audience understand the problem better

Comment: Hi this is my first time here, I couldn't add a photo as I don't have that kind of priviledge yet so here's a link to a screen cap on my flickr account https://www.flickr.com/photos/vivanteart/20000110453/in/dateposted/